# Ms Excel or other Programming language to create calculate formula

Tags: excel, formula, calculation

i will give an example how to manually calculate, eg: the price is 2,000,000.00 and what i want to calculate is first 100,000.00 is 1% tax, second is 101,000.00 untill 500,000.00 is 2% tax, third is 500,001 to 1,000,000.00 is 3% tax and the last number higher is 1,000,000.00 above is cap at 4% tax.
Basically what i want do is if we calculate 100,000.00 it must be minus from amount 2,000,000.00.

100,000.00x1%=1,000.00

400,000.00x2%=8,000.00

500,000.00x3%=15,000.00

1,000.000.00x4%=40,000.00

and after that all total tax is 64,000.00.

how to create formula to calculate on excel or calculate on other programming language.

Comment: Use if condition, it is very easy

Comment: Setup a tax table then use `VLookUP()` or `Index/Match` or `XLookUP` formula.

Comment: See the formula, if it works?  You may have given an example to illustrate it clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in excel , If amount values are in A1 and downwards

```
=IF(A1<100000, A1*0.01, IF(A1<500000,(A1-100000)*0.02+1000,IF(A1<1000000,(A1-500000)*0.03+9000,(A1-1000000)*0.04+24000)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank bro, it work, even though i don't understand formula that you gave me, later i will study about this formula.

Comment: Nothing complex in it.  first decide the bracket, reduce the previous bracket level from it, calculate tax of current bracket on residual amaount add the previous cumulative tax.

Comment: e.g. if 600,000 it will deduct `500,000` from it calculate 3% tax on balance (100,000) and add 9000 (tax on (500000) to it.

Comment: may i know, why u add 1000 for 2%, 9000 for 3% and 24000 for 4%.

Comment: 9,000(1000+8000) is tax for first 500,000 and 24,000 (1000+8000+15000) is tax for first 10,000,000